# How to spawn a terminal when executing a compiled C program?

Tags: terminal, redhat-enterprise-linux, xorg, c

I've overwritten the gnome-screenshot program to suit my needs in getting a screenshot from a secondary home-made graphics card output and now when I press the PrintScreen button it executes it (as desired).  However, there are some "printf" statements in the program (written in C) that I would like to be able to see as output.  Is there any way to do this?  Perhaps by spawning a terminal when the program executes?

Running:  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.8 (Tikanga)

Comment: You could try using a script to pipe the output to an stdout window.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  Example perhaps?

Comment: Seth Noble has posted a great answer detailing this.

Comment: I guess I was confused because when I try what he mentioned it creates a "1" file and the log file.  I added opening the log in gedit as a second script command after it finishes but didn't know if there was a way for a terminal window instead of a file.

Comment: what happens when you pipe the output to `echo`?  (i.e. run `myprscr | echo`)

Comment: Runs the program but doesn't open anything... hrmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to capture the output would be to wrap your PrintScreen command in a shell and redirect the output to a file.  For example, if your program is named `myprscr`, the shell script might be:

```
#!/bin/sh
myprscr 2>1 1>>/tmp/myprscr.log
```

Then have the PrintScreen button run that shell script instead of the your command.  You will probably want use the full path for `myprscr`.

Comment: Yeah I think this is going to be the winning answer.  And to think I went through all that trouble of making a little ASCII progress bar *weep*.

Comment: Just FYI would upvote but I don't have enough karma.

Comment: Trying this now, but the output isn't displayed until after the myprscr is completely finished... anyway to do it in "real time?"

Comment: You could open another terminal and do `tail -f /tmp/myprscr.log`